# Haskell read Integer and list of lists from file

Tags: list, haskell

Lets say I have a file

```
8 [[1,2,3,4],[1,2]]
```

with number and list of lists in it.

This code allow me to read all line or n-th element from it.

```
import System.IO

main = do
      x <- openFile "file.txt" ReadMode
      cont <- hGetContents x
      let fLines = lines cont
      let numb = fLines !! 0 !! 0
      print numb
```

here `numb` is `'8'`.

How can I get integer 8 from `numb` without using other libraries?

And is there a possibility to read list of lists and use it as list of lists?

Or should I better write each list in a new row, and read them row by row and add to empty list?

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I didn't find any example of doing something like that on internet.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Fractal  answer I've managed to write this

```
rList :: String -> [[Int]]    
rList = read
```

which is working for list of lists!

However, when I cant make it work with single Int.

```
into :: String -> Int
into = read
```

Don't know why, but it doesn't work for `numb` T_T

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, it was kinda stupid. `numb` is Char here, so to make it work it will be enough to write

```
print (into [numb])
```

Thank you all for answers.

Comment: Is the index always going to be a one-digit number? You would probably be better served by looking for the first space, in that example.

Comment: Rather than indexing into `flines` with `!!`, it might be better to split at whitespace with [`words`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words). That way it is more flexible, and you won't have to convert the leading `Char` back to a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) to parse `String` representations of Haskell data structures. This should work for your list of lists as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ord` function `:: Char -> Int`

That function could be found searching for the `Char -> Int` type signature on the Hoogle search engine: http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Int

Documentation: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord

Example:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Char (ord)

main = do x <- openFile "file.txt" ReadMode
          cont <- hGetContents x
          let fLines = lines cont
          let numb = fLines !! 0 !! 0
          let numbInt = ord numb - ord '0'
          print numbInt
```